# How to extract numbers from a string SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ts there a way to extract numbers from a string?

In my database there is a column called `Reference` and it contains multiple numbers

`CM|319|14163|||109|405000`

Is there a way to get the first number like this?

`select CM|%s|... as ParentId from table`

So the output should be `319`

And maybe even multiple like

`select CM|...|%s|... as SiblingId, CM|%s|... as ParentId from table`

`14163` `319`

Comment: What is your DB?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products have their own, non-ANSI, string functions.)

Comment: Im using microsoft sql studio I think its mssql but im not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We might be able to use `PATINDEX` here along with a substring operation.  We can find the position of the first number in the string, and then take a substring until one position past the first occurrence of a number *followed* by a pipe character.

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(val,
                 PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', val),
                 PATINDEX('%[0-9]|%', val) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', val) + 1)
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

**Data:**

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'CM|319|14163|||109|405000' AS val
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if using sql2017 or later...
maybe?

```
CREATE TABLE #yourtable(
   reference VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO #yourtable(reference) VALUES ('CM|319|14163|||109|405000');
INSERT INTO #yourtable(reference) VALUES ('CMff123|14163|||109AA|4ZXC05000');


SELECT reference,
       TRIM(REPLACE(TRANSLATE(reference,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',REPLICATE('|',26)),'|',' ')) AS extracted
FROM #yourtable
```